# How to find if a particular service is run/started when JBOSS AS is started?

Tags: java, service, ant, jboss, wildfly

Beginner here! I have two questions.

***Background:***

I have installed a program (following their installation instructions) by downloading a `.zip` file and then unzipping it, and then deploying it by executing **`ant deploy`**. According to the installation instructions, this deploys my program as a JBOSS AS Service.

Now I want to run the service. According to the user manual of the deployed program, starting the JBoss Application Server will run the service. But the user manual instructs to run a script named **`run.sh`** in `<jboss-install-directory>/bin` folder. But there is no script named `run.sh` in my `<jboss-install-directory>/bin` folder. So I started the JBoss AS using the usual **`./standalone.sh`**.

***Question 1:***

What is meant by a JBoss AS SERVICE?

***Question 2:***

How can I find a list of all services started/run when JBoss AS is started? 
So that I can confirm that my service has been started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "JBoss AS" service, I guess that we are talking about JBoss in version 7.x, because later versions are either named Wildfly (community edition) or JBoss EAP (enterprise edition).

The JBoss [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Application+deployment) explains the two different deployment modes: automatic or manual. If you did not change anything in the configuration file standalone.xml (as your are starting this configuration), then the automatic mode may be active. In this case JBoss AS deploys your application (which you name "service") automatically and indicates the status by a marker file (for more details see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Application+deployment#Applicationdeployment-MarkerFiles)).