# Why doesn't my JBoss AS bin directory contain a run.sh script?

Tags: java, bash, unix, jboss, restcomm

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and I need to install and run Restcomm JSS7 stack as a JBoss AS Service.

I followed [this video tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjewPXtmJrVAhUCRhQKHbAYBasQtwIIJDAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DyUJSMclEi-g&usg=AFQjCNF76RPTjvHMmYQ72rEK3Npe5slueA) to install JBoss AS 7. Then I set the `JBOSS_HOME` environment variable to installation directory of JBoss AS 7. As a result, I was able to start the JBoss AS *successfully* by executing **`./run.sh`** in the `bin` sub-folder of the installation directory.

Then I followed [this guide](http://documentation.telestax.com/core/ss7/SS7_Stack_Installation_Guide.html#_jdk_installing_configuring_and_running) to install Restcomm JSS7 stack. For that, I downloaded `restcomm-jss7-7.4.1404.zip`, unzipped it to `/opt/` and then navigated to the `ss7-jboss` sub-directory and then executed **`ant deploy`**, 
and the result was

```
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

which according to the guide is an indication of the service deployed successfully.

Then I am following CHAPTER 4 SECTION 4.1 of [this user manual](http://documentation.telestax.com/core/ss7/SS7_Stack_User_Guide.html#_running_ss7_service) to ***run*** it as a JBoss AS Service. According to it,

> All you have to do to start the Service is start the JBoss AS. This
>   will automatically start the SS7 Service. To start the JBoss Server
>   you must execute the run.sh (Unix) or run.bat (Microsoft Windows)
>   startup script in the /bin folder (on Unix or
>   Windows).

***TWO PROBLEMS:***

1. My **`<jboss_install_directory>/bin`** does NOT have a `run.sh` script. *Because of this reason, I tried by running JBoss AS by using the regular **`standalone.sh`** script.*
2. Next in the user manual, it is stated:

> Result: If the service started properly you should see following lines
>   in the Unix terminal or Command Prompt depending on your environment:

(**Note:** I have [pasted the following excerpt from user manual **here**](https://pastebin.com/1z08fdJx), since it is too long to paste in this question.)

But I see none of those lines in my terminal. Rather, my terminal output of running **`./standalone.sh`** is [pasted **here**.](https://pastebin.com/MGsB9p5r)

So I don't know how and where to proceed from here. Please help.

---

***NOTE:*** This question is NOT a duplicate of my other question. Like I mentioned in the question titles, this question is about why my JBoss AS installation doesn't contain a `run.sh` script, and what would be its alternative. The other question is about some possible command to find out the JBoss Services started when it is running? When a beginner is starting to learn something, their entire purpose Not getting the job done. They have many confusions/questions in their mind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find if a particular service is run/started when JBOSS AS is started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233855/how-to-find-if-a-particular-service-is-run-started-when-jboss-as-is-started). Please don't repost the same question if you don't get an answer. Improve the original question to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @RobinTopper Thank you for the advice. But they are not duplicates. I explained that in the note in the end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation documents how to start a JBoss 5.1 server but your installation uses a JBoss 7.1 server, which is why you have to use `standalone.sh` instead of `run.sh` to start the server and why the logs are different.

<strike>Since you correctly reach the `JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started in 3955ms` line I wouldn't worry too much (except about using a documentation that is clearly outdated).</strike>

The documentation of your product only declares [compatibility](http://documentation.telestax.com/core/ss7/SS7_Stack_Installation_Guide.html#pre-requisites) with JBoss 5.1.0. While it may work on later releases, you might want to check if there's a more recent version of your product. I wouldn't recommend installing JBoss AS 5.1.0 as it isn't supported anymore and will contain security breaches.